# httpd server service location?

Tags: apache

Following is not working.

/etc/init.d https restart
serive httpd restart

I don't see any file related to httpd in /etc/init.d

Although httpd server is running fine. httpd.conf file is also not present in /etc.
where should i look?

Please help in restarting the service.

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify which distro you are using?

- Ubuntu 12.04LTS: `service apache2 restart`
- Debian 6: `service apache2 restart`
- Redhat: `/sbin/service httpd restart`

Answer (score 0):

Centos 7:

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/httpd.service
```

Which points to:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service
```